# How to sort twice in SQL with time and boolean

Tags: sql

This is my table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `matches` (
    `no` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `matchID` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `teamOne` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `teamTwo` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `schedule` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `isVisible` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    `isDone` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    `isCancelled` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    `isStarted` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`no`)
);
```

And this is my current query

```sql
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE isVisible = 1 ORDER BY schedule ASC
```

it's working correctly and sorted according to the schedule.
But I want to make all the isDone records in the bottom while still sorting according to the schedule. Here is an example output that I want:

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
| matchID   | schedule | isDone |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example10 | 04:00    | 0      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example40 | 05:00    | 0      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example65 | 06:00    | 0      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example42 | 07:00    | 0      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example13 | 02:00    | 1      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example69 | 03:00    | 1      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| example50 | 03:30    | 1      |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

thanks

Comment: So you want to sort by `isDone` first, and by `schedule` second. Okay, and what is actually stopping you now?

Comment: `ORDER BY isDone  schedule`

Comment: You are aware order by can have multiple objects right?   and each can be asc or desc depending on need?  You can even use case expressions...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Question (and answer) contains product specific construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place multiple columns inside ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE isVisible = 1 ORDER BY isDone, schedule ASC
```